# C# :httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to set value of referer parameter of httpwebrequest header, but it is giving error-

Function that I am using (C#):

```
webRequest.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.microsoft.com");
```

Error:

```
Invalid parameters. A required parameter is not found or contains invalid value.
```

Comment: Please show me the code.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx)  If you post your code I can better help you out.

```
HttpWebRequest    myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
// Set referer property  to http://www.microsoft.com .
myHttpWebRequest.Referer="http://www.microsoft.com";
// Assign the response object of 'HttpWebRequest' to a 'HttpWebResponse' variable.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
// Display the contents of the page to the console.
Stream streamResponse=myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader( streamResponse );
Char[] readBuffer = new Char[256];
int count = streamRead.Read( readBuffer, 0, 256 );
Console.WriteLine("\nThe contents of HTML page are.......");    
while (count > 0) 
{
    String outputData = new String(readBuffer, 0, count);
    Console.Write(outputData);
    count = streamRead.Read(readBuffer, 0, 256);
}
Console.WriteLine("\nHTTP Request  Headers :\n\n{0}",myHttpWebRequest.Headers);
Console.WriteLine("\nHTTP Response Headers :\n\n{0}",myHttpWebResponse.Headers);    
streamRead.Close();
streamResponse.Close();
// Release the response object resources.
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Referer to the site is:{0}",myHttpWebRequest.Referer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is typical use:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("");
req.Referer = "http://www.google.com";
```

Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

**There are some reserved HTTP Headers which you can't set** via `webRequest.Headers.Set` Referer is one of them.

For these there is always a special property to set.

In your case `webRequest.Referer = "http://google.com"` will do.

Answer (score 0):

@kedar kamthe, you can't put HttpRequestHeader.Referer in there, because that is expecting a value, I believe, but not sure... I think you wanted to use this:

webRequest.Headers.Set("Referer", "http://www.microsoft.com");

But you should use it as Chris Ballance's example. That should work, but if that doesn't work, just try as I show above ;).

You should put your code here, so we can see what is wrong.